# What to use as base for a custom MXML component?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, flex4.5, custom-component

I'm using several custom MXML components in my Flex 4.5 application.

They all use absolute coordinates to place Image, Label, Line, etc. components and are currently based on a [spark.components.BorderContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/BorderContainer.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    width="160" height="140" borderWeight="0" 
    creationComplete="init(event)">

    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Image id="_avatar" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="120" />
    <s:Label id="_username" x="1" y="122" width="80" /> 
    <s:Label id="_bid" x="80" y="122" width="40" textAlign="center" /> 
    <s:Label id="_trix" x="120" y="122" width="36" textAlign="right" />
        .... and so on: Images, Labels, Paths, Lines, Rects .... 
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Then I've realized, that I probably don't have to use BorderContainer, because I don't draw/need any borders around my custom components.

But I don't know, what to take instead of it.

I've tried taking <mx:UIComponent> (and removing <s:Layout> tag above), but then I get the error:

```
'Image' declaration must be contained within the <Declarations> tag since it does not implement 'mx.core.IUIComponent'.
'Label' declaration must be contained within the <Declarations> tag since it does not implement 'mx.core.IUIComponent'.
```

Any suggestions please? Is there some simplest possible spark "container"? And do I need a "container" at all if I use (and want to use) absolute coordinates?

Comment: What is the code that gives you that error?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com `UIComponent` hasn't `DefaultProperty` metatag declaration so if you're inherited your MXML component from `UIComponent` in Flex >= 4 it can't handle MXML children properly. To handle them properly as properties Flex compiler requires put them in `Declarations` tag. I see no problems here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use `s:Group`. And you can omit `layout` declaration as far as `BasicLayout` is default layout.

`UIComponent` isn't container so it hasn't default placeholder for children to add them with MXML.

Comment: I know the OP isn't asking for graphics right now, but I'll just add this anyway: if you need the 'simplest possible spark container' that you can skin, subclass [SkinnableContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html).

Comment: @RIAstar `SkinnableContainer` isn't intended to be extended with MXML. It is recommended to be extended with ActionScript.

Comment: You're right, my bad. It's just that when I see 'custom component' I automatically think 'ActionScript'.